# What backend should I use to serve multiple websites, e.g. wordpress, web apps and mobile apps?

Tags: django, mongodb, nginx, digital-ocean, uwsgi

I am just starting to learn back end development, recently learned php and wordpress development, and I don't know what I should learn next. 
The image below shows what I want to set up, and the software I think, but don't know if, I can use to achieve this.

Can I use a droplet on digitalocean and with django, nginx and uWSGI use that to host multiple static websites, wordpress websites and web apps. Can I also use the same server to communicate with mobile apps (created with flutter)?

Is this even possible, and what software do I need to use?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pleas before asking any question google your question then ask.
There are no limits to the number of the services that you can host and deploy on your server or vps if you have enough resources on your machine.

To host a Web site or deploy a service  there a lot of ways to do that, all you have to do is just google what ever you think you want to do, just google the question and the google will show you the path.